# Fill exact pattern in String

Tags: c#, replace, guid

I have a textbox. The textbox contains the pattern of a guid, looking like:

{0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

I want the user, who types in the textbox, to only replace the zeros with their value.

F.e.
I type "ABC123456789" the GUID should look like {ABC1234-5678-9000-0000-000000000000}

I tried something like:

```
string tmp = "";
tmp = textBox1.Text.Substring(replaceIndex, 1);

if (textBox1.Text.Length > replaceIndex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tmp);
    if (tmp == "-")
        replaceIndex++;

    textBox1.Select(replaceIndex, 1);
    replaceIndex++;
}
```

Which works partly. I have problems with the user deleting chars. F.e. if my GUID contains:
{ABC1234-5 **|** 678-9000-0000-000000000000}

My cursor is positioned at the "**|**". If I press backspace (or mark a substring f.e. C1234 and press delete) I want the 5 removed and replaced with 0 again.

I think I've got some troubles with the index or my logic is completely wrong. Please tell me if so.

I've tried to solve it like:

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
{
    replaceIndex--;
    int tmpIndex = replaceIndex;
    string xReplace = defaultGUID.Substring(tmpIndex, 1);
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Insert(tmpIndex, xReplace);
}
```

Maybe there's a complete different solution to my problem I haven't thought about. Thank you in advance.

//Edit: Working with WindowsForms.

Comment: Such functionality is already provided by [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx). You can set your own prompt character through the [PromptChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.promptchar(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos While your comment is correct, it only applies to winforms. What if the OP is using asp.net or wpf?

Comment: Is that wpf? asp.net? winforms?

Comment: Then 1) The OP should be specific. You can have masked controls in Javascript too and 2) I don't think ASP.NET provides the Keys enumeration

Comment: In WPF [a similar control](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/MaskedTextBox) is provided by the [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit). It started as a Microsoft/Community project but was taken over by Xceed countless years ago.

Comment: @Chris - Please be specific about which UI framework you are using (WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET, etc), or this question is likely to be closed by the community. It is not possible to give you an answer without this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said MaskedTextbox was the hint I've needed.
If someone else has the same problem, here's my solution based on the answer of  Panagiotis Kanavos. Thank you very much.

```
MaskBox.Mask = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}";
MaskBox.PromptChar = '0';
```

And, to ensure I always get a full GUID, even when not filled, I replace the spaces with zeros:

```
MaskBox.Text.Replace(" ", "0");
```

Because you only get the filled parts back from the textbox, like:
0123____-____-____-3210_____

Thank you for your support. I would've marked your answer as correct, but you posted a comment.

Best greetings